# Checking Validation for Credit Card Number

Tags: validation, netbeans, checksum

I'm in an Intro to Java class, and I'm having trouble writing a checksum algorithm for a credit card validation program. The requirements are:

- Beginning with the 2nd digit from the right and working right to left, double every-other digit; if the resulting number is greater than or equal to 10, subtract 9.  Add each resulting number together.
- Then, beginning with the last digit on the right and working right to left, add every-other digit to the running total used in the previous step.
- If the resulting total is evenly divisible by 10, the credit card number is valid.
- When coding this algorithm, keep in mind that not all credit card numbers have the same number of digits.

It is also stated that we need to use a loop(s) to complete this. I understand that I'll probably need a for loop but I'm just stuck on how to finish it. This is what I have:

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String cardNumber) {
        //your code here
        int i, checkSum = 0;

        // Compute checksum of every other digit starting from right-most digit
        for (i = cardNumber.Length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            checkSum += (cardNumber[i] - '0');
        }

      // Now take digits not included in first checksum, multiple by two,
        // and compute checksum of resulting digits
        for (i = cardNumber.Length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            int val = ((cardNumber[i] - '0') * 2);
            while (val > 0) {
                checkSum += (val % 10);
                val /= 10;
            }
        }

        // Number is valid if sum of both checksums MOD 10 equals 0
        return ((checkSum % 10) == 0);
    }
```

I'm getting errors at both for loops.
Any help?

Comment: Your for loops are using the same variable (`i`), change the nested for loop to use something like for (int j = cardNumber.Length - 2; j >= 0; j -= 2)

Comment: @Andrew thanks! However I'm still getting errors that say "array required, but String found" where I have [ i ] and [ j ]..do you know how i could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

- To find the length of the string use [string.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) not string.Length
- To get char from a string at a given index use [string.charAt(index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

  ```
  public static boolean isValidNumber(String cardNumber) {
  //your code here
  int i, checkSum = 0;

  //To find the length of the string use string.length() not string.Length
  for (i = cardNumber.length() - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
      //to get char from a string at a given position use string.charAt(index)
      checkSum += (cardNumber.charAt(i) - '0');
  }

  for (i = cardNumber.length() - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
      int val = ((cardNumber.charAt(i) - '0') * 2);
      while (val > 0) {
          checkSum += (val % 10);
          val /= 10;
      }
  }

  // Number is valid if sum of both checksums MOD 10 equals 0
  return ((checkSum % 10) == 0);
  }
  ```